# Different R-squared for equivalent models

Tags: r, lm

Why do I get different values of R-squared for these two models, which should be equivalent (in the second model, the intercept term is replaced by a level of z)? Is this a bug or am I missing something?

```r
set.seed(42)

N=100

# intercepts
iA = 3
iB = 3.5
# slopes
sA = 1.5
sB = 0.5
# xs
xA = runif(0,1, n=N)
xB = runif(0,1, n=N)
# ys
yA = sA*xA + iA + rnorm(n=N)/10
yB = sB*xB + iB + rnorm(n=N)/10

data = data.frame(x=c(xA, xB), y=c(yA, yB), z=c(rep("A", times=N), rep("B", times=N)))

lm1 = lm(data=data, formula = y ~ x + z)
lm2 = lm(data=data, formula = y ~ x + z -1)

coef(lm1)
coef(lm2)

summary(lm1)$r.squared
summary(lm2)$r.squared
```

Output:

```
> coef(lm1)
(Intercept)           x          zB 
 3.23590275  1.03353472 -0.01435266 
> coef(lm2)
       x       zA       zB 
1.033535 3.235903 3.221550 
> 
> summary(lm1)$r.squared
[1] 0.7552991
> summary(lm2)$r.squared
[1] 0.9979477
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For models with an intercept `summary.lm` calculates an R^2 based on comparing the model to the intercept only model.  For a model without an intercept that does not make sense so it compares it to the zero model.  Of course in your example the intercept is actually a linear combination of columns in the model matrix, i.e. `all(model.matrix(lm2) %*% c(0, 1, 1) == 1)` is TRUE so it would be possible to write software to check for whether the intercept is a submodel of the full model but as it is it only looks to see if the model formula specifies an intercept or not.

In terms of calculations for models with an intercept `summary.lm` uses the equivalent of

```
1 - sum(resid(lm1)^2) / sum((data$y - mean(data$y))^2)
## [1] 0.7552991

1 - sum(resid(lm2)^2) / sum((data$y - mean(data$y))^2)
## [1] 0.7552991
```

but for models without an intercept `summary.lm` drops the mean term

```
1 - sum(resid(lm2)^2) / sum(data$y^2)
## [1] 0.9979477
```

You can compare these to

```
summary(lm1)$r.squared
## [1] 0.7552991

summary(lm2)$r.squared
## [1] 0.9979477
```

See `?summary.lm` where this is mentioned.

Comment: Thank you - I can see how this makes sense in general. It seems a bit odd that the `-1` simultaneously adds another level for the categorical variable though.

Comment: For lm2 the model matrix consists of 3 columns:: x, an indicator of  zA and an indicator of zB.  For the intercept model the model matrix consists of the x and an indicator of zB  as wellas the intercept so it is really that it dropped zA in the intercept model.

Answer (score 2):

From `help("summary.lm")` (emphasis added):

> R², the ‘fraction of variance explained by the model’,
>
> R^2 = 1 - \frac{\sum_i{R_i^2}}{\sum_i(y_i- y^*)^2},
>
> where y^* is the mean of y_i
> **if there is an intercept and zero otherwise**.

If you remove the intercept, R² is defined differently (which is sensible from the perspective of a statistician).

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that I should look at the documentation of `summary.lm` rather than of `summary`. Could you explain why this is sensible from the perspective of a statistician?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/26205/11849

Comment: I see, because the baseline is an intercept-only model, and with `-1` we essentially force a zero intercept.